# Facebook Graph API : setting width on videos

Tags: php, css, facebook-graph-api

guys. I'm pulling some videos from a facebook page but they come in different sizes. I was wondering if I could pass the width and height through parameters on the json link or something like that to get them to be the same size overall.

I've already tried doing this with css and searching through facebook's docs but I wasn't successful.

Code:

```
$gerarAcc = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=
{$appId}&client_secret={$appSecret}&grant_type=client_credentials";
$access_tokenJson = file_get_contents($gerarAcc);
$access_token = json_decode($access_tokenJson, true);

$fields = "id,title,description,created_time,from,source";
$limit = 4;

$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{$fb_page_id}/videos?access_token={$access_token['access_token']}&fields={$fields}&limit={$limit}";
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);

$obj = json_decode($json, true);

$feed_item_count = count($obj['data']);

  for($x=0; $x<$feed_item_count; $x++){

        // video source
        $source = $obj['data'][$x]['source'];

        // display Facebook page video
       echo "<div class='col-md-12'>";
          echo "<div class='slider'>";
            echo "<video controls class='embed-responsive-item'>";
               echo "<source src={$source} type=video/mp4> data-sizes='100vw'";
            echo "</video>";
        echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";

    }
```

Comment: Do you have a sample page @Luciano?

Comment: @Chris Chen Only locally :(

Comment: wouldn't <video width="xxx" height="xxx"> do the job for you?